# Ext JS: generally frustrated with height and width issues

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs

Does anybody else wrestle with problems related to width and height of panels and containers?  Let the browser handle (autowidth) or specify height and width?  How best to leave room for a vertical scrollbar? How best to avoid horizontal scrollbars? hbox and vbox cause me no end of trouble. And when everything is perfect in FF, there is always some width bug to handle in IE.  I suspect I have written too many resize handlers - I expect the framework to handle this. Are there secrets related to layouts that might help developers?

Can anybody point me to some general guidance related to height/width best practices with Ext JS?

Comment: ExtJS is very unfriendly to autosizing, unfortunately.  I have to struggle with it all the time.  It's insane to have fixed sizes in a multilanguage application with a shitton of pages providing dynamic information...  Also, ExtJS 4 is generally better with sizing, but so far buggy especially if you don't have the commercial license.

Comment: Give us an example of your issues and maybe we can help. Generally, the most common mistake is to over-nest and use layouts improperly, which causes Ext to re size components incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha appears to be addressing some issues in 4.x.

http://www.sencha.com/blog/inside-the-ext-js-4-1-layout-system?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRokuaTNZKXonjHpfsX56uUvX6a1lMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4HTMp0dvycMRAVFZl5nR9dFOOdfQ%3D%3D

Comment: external link not available ( the reason why it should be avoided)